# Openlayers map not using full width

Tags: angular, flexbox, openlayers, here-api, openlayers-6

I am using **openlayers** on **Angular** to display a map with **here-api** as the map tile provider.
**Openlayers 6.1.1**
**Angular 8.0.0**

However, when the page is loaded the map does not fill the whole width.
This happens on Edge & Chrome for Windows (PC), and Chrome on Android.

In Windows, the map will use the whole width only when the browser window is resized.
In Android, the width is filled when the map is scrolled out of view and back in to view again.

The screenshots below demonstrates what the map looks like before & after resizing the browser.
**Partial width map on initial display** 
[image]

**Map uses full width after window resize**
[image]

My Angular component map config looks like this:

```
addCommonProjections();
this.source = new XYZ({
  url: 'https://{1-4}.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com' +
    '/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day/{z}/{x}/{y}/512/png?apiKey=someApiKey',
  attributions: 'Map Tiles &copy; ' + new Date().getFullYear() + ' developer.here.com'
});

this.layer = new TileLayer({
  source: this.source
});

this.view = new View({
  center: fromLonLat([this.property.longitude, this.property.latitude ]),
  zoom: 16
});

this.map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  interactions: defaultInteractions({
    onFocusOnly: true
  }),
  layers: [this.layer],
  view: this.view
});
```

The html template looks like this:

```
<div tabindex="1" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;" id="map"></div>
```

To eliminate the map tile provider **here-api** as the cause of the problem, I also tried subsituting the **XYZ.url** in the Angular component map config with **openstreetmap**:

> https://{a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png

But this resulted in the same problem as above, so I suspect this may be an issue with openlayers.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.
Thank you!

**QUESTION UPDATED: 20th Feb 2020**

The suggestion from @sep7696 led me to dig deeper into the browser elements.
On inspecting the "ol-layer" divs, I was able to see a  tag with width set to "274", which is not the full width of the screen (screen width 375).

I have highlighted the width attribute of the  tag in question:

[image: Map canvas set to width 275]

As you can see, the screen is 375 but the canvas width has been set to 274 for some reason.

I should add that I am also using **flex-layout**, which I omitted previously for clarity in the question but feel I should now incase it might be a side effect of flexbox.

Does anyone know why the **canvas** is set to 274, or how I can set the  width to 100%?

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to get the map to show full width by calling the openlayers **PluggableMap.updateSize()** method in a **setTimeout()**. The setTimeout allows the map time to initialise before **updateSize()** is called on it.

[Openlayers API updateSize() ref](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_PluggableMap-PluggableMap.html#updateSize)

According to openlayers doc this forces the map to recalculate the viewport size if thirdparty code changes the size of the viewport.

Angular code:

```
setTimeout(() => { this.map.updateSize(); });
```

This fixes my problem. The map is shown to the full width allocated to it now.

**Possible cause:**

Maybe **flex-layout / Flexbox** was adjusting element sizes resulting in the side-effect shown above.
Further evidence of conflict was seen when the **map** div is placed in a <**div**> containing flex-layout attributes (E.g. fxLayoutAlign, fxLayout etc). In this case, the map will not even be displayed.
Something to bear in mind when using openlayers on a page with flex-layout (or Flexbox?).

Comment: I got the exact problem and resolved with this way. Thanks for the very detailed question and also the great answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use DevTools of your browser and set width=100% for div with class names "ol-viewport" , "ol-unselectable ol-layers" ,"ol-layer" , "ol-overlaycontainer-stopevent"
if its not work either change direction of Your map

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have checked each of the divs you mentioned (**ol-viewport, ol-unselectable ol-layers, ol-layer**) and they already have **width: 100%** set.
Your suggestion has led me further however. There are two "ol-layer" divs, both containing **<canvas>** tags. The <canvas> tag in the first "ol-layer" div has **width="274"**, which is not the full width of the screen (screen width is 375). This appears to be the problem. I will update my question with this information.

Comment: maybe cause of direction of your div tags 
i can better answer if i can see it in plunker or something else

Answer (score 0):

To display the map, I started `updateSize()` after 10 seconds otherwise it did not work

```
window.omap = this.map;

setTimeout(() => {
    window.omap.updateSize();
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're using Angular i suppose you're initializing the map in `ngOnInit()`, so the canvas is drawn before any html is being rendered, that's why resizing solves the problem, use `ngAfterViewInit()` instead.